# Why do I see duplicate SharePoint Online cmdlets in the PowerShell 7 help system?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powershell-module, help-system

This is on a new install of PowerShell 7.0.0 from 2020-03-26:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help Get-SPOSite -online

Name                              Category  Module
----                              --------  ------
Get-SPOSite                       Cmdlet    Microsoft.Online.SharePo… 
Get-SPOSite                       Cmdlet    Microsoft.online.sharePo… 
Get-Help: Multiple Help topics were found. Use only one Help topic with the -Online option.
```

Notice the `.Online` and `.online` difference in the `Module` names.  I suppose I could delete and start over, however I would rather have someone here save from me that.  I don't know if that will make a difference, anyway.

Comment: Thanks Bacon. A number of things I don't understand from the help files on this site. The request that a fence be placed around the code for one. I tried to comply but I must have gotten it wrong since you removed them. My attempt to emulate white-space with _ was also rejected however I wish I had studied your edits better before accepting them. How did you create white-space in the code example. I figured there must be a way to have the formatting just work from pasted code.

Comment: If you click the "edited X hours ago" link you can see the different Markdown between [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60909733/revisions).  The code "fence" it was referring to was three backticks (```), or you can also indent each line by four spaces.  More formatting information is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).  By the way, if you prefix a user name with an @ (e.g. @BACON) it will notify them of your comment, although usually they have to have already commented first; I'm not sure if performing an edit alone makes someone a comment "target".